# How to use Filter to get Boolean - Scala Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have AccountTable:

```
import models.{Account, Category}
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfig}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.lifted.Tag
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Writes, Json}

object AccountTable extends AccountTable

trait AccountTable extends HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]{
  val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)

  class Accounts(tag: Tag) extends Table[Account](tag, "account") {

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def login = column[String]("login")

    def password = column[String]("password")

    def * = (id, login, password) <> ((Account.apply _).tupled, Account.unapply)
  }

  val accounts = TableQuery[Accounts]

  implicit val accountFormat = Json.format[Account]


  def auth(login: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    db.run(findByLogin(login, password).result.headOption)
  }

  private def findByLogin(login: String, password: String) = accounts.filter(x => (x.password === password && x.login === login))
}
```

I try to develop `auth` method. I really don't understand, how to complete this method. I tried different ways, but always I get different errors.

Comment: What is the auth method supposed to do?

Comment: @pedrofurla, just check, that there is row in DB with this login and password.

Comment: Still, the name `auth` alone tell me nothing about what it is supposed to do. How are all the other methods related to that? It would be very helpful if you could show us what you tried, what error you got etc... And remove all irrelevant parts of the sample code.

Comment: Found the method auth now. What errors do you get?

Comment: @pedrofurla, I removed part of code.

Comment: @pedrofurla, the problem is method `auth` does not return Boolean. It does nothing. I cannot call it from my controller.

Comment: Try this `def auth(login: String, password: String): Boolean = db.run(findByLogin(login, password).result.headOption).isDefined`, it is this or change to `Future[Boolean]`, or Await.result on the future.

Comment: @pedrofurla, cannot resolve symbol isDefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
def auth(login: String, password: String): Future[Boolean] = {
  val action = findByLogin(login, password).result.headOption
    .map(authOpt => authOpt.getOrElse(false))      
  db.run(action)
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
def auth(login: String, password: String): Boolean = {
  val action = findByLogin(login, password).result.headOption
    .map(authOpt => authOpt.getOrElse(false))           
  Await.result(db.run(action), 5 seconds)
}
```

The code above is untested, but you should get the idea behind queries in slick. I assumed that auth should return `false` if no result was found in the db.

One last word: I strongly recommend to use option 1 and work with [`Future`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html), as `Await.result` blocks the thread from execution.